# Видео как задний фон формы

Tags: css

Как сделать так что-бы видео проигрывалось внутри div'а и на него можно было наложить фон.
Если убрать position: absolute с блока видео то видео обрезается с помощью overflow: hidden, но тогда фон не устанавливается на видео (rgba)

http://codepen.io/Aloving/pen/eBeOaw

```
 <div class="circle">
   <video src="file.mp4" autoplay="" loop="" muted"></video>
 </div>

    .circle{
        position: absolute;
        top:calc(50% - 100px);
        left: calc(50% - 100px);
        border-radius: 50%;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        background-color: rgba(94, 121, 209, 0.5);
    }
    .circle video{
        position: absolute;
        z-index: -1;
        width: 400px;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, к примеру, создать внутри еще один контейнер, закруглить ему углы и с ним уже работать

http://codepen.io/pen/NbwWBV

```
.circle {
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(50% - 100px);
    left: calc(50% - 100px);
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

.circle video{
    width: 400px;
}

.circle_inner {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; top: 0;
    background-color: rgba(94, 121, 209, 0.5);
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```